# How to display date from database table to a date textfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio, date

I have a database table with a column `Birthdate`. I want to display the date from the db table to a 'date' textfield on my webform.

For example, the data in my database table `Birthdate` column is 'Sep 18, 2000' and I want to display it on the 'date' textfield with a format of `dd/mm/yyyy`.

This is what I have did but it does not display anything on the 'date' textfield

Code in Webform1.aspx.cs

```
string date = DataAccess.BrgyCitizenBirthdate;
DateTime getBDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MMM dd, yyyy", null));
BCBirthdate = getBDate.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

Note that the value of `DataAccess.BrgyCitizenBirthdate;` is Sep 18, 2000.

Code in Webform2.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtBirthdate.Text = Brgy_Citizens.BCBirthdate;
}
```

My output

[image]

My **DESIRED** output

[image]

Comment: Use the Convert.ToDateTime method to convert the date display format: Convert.ToDateTime("2012-12-21").ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
txtBirthdate.Text = Brgy_Citizens.BCBirthdate.ToShortDateString();
```

You don't really want to use fixed formatting, since that may well change.

But, as a FYI?

this would work (it is MM, and not mm)

```
getBDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Well, you kind have to make a choice here.

that date setting is going to be the result of regional settings on the client side.

And you can well see the default settings - just look at the default date setting when you drop in that text box + textmode = date.

So, for the simple answer?

Shove into that text box a date formatted to what the text box is expecting.

I thus suggest using ToShortDateString, and it should work if the date settings are different or changed on the web server.